# login.microsoft.com - Azure - Multiple login not working

Tags: azure, authentication, windows-10, azure-active-directory

I'm not sure whether I've phrased the title of the question in a right manner.

We have different login/account in our organinzation, For eg, For outlook email we have one account, and for accessing our project/application we need to use a different ID's across DEV/QA/Staging environment.

The issue is, whenever we login in any one of the above given scenario, it is being redirected through the Azure (through login.microsoft.com) and when we open up a different browser window with another URL, it is still taking the previous cookies and the login fails with an error.

We currently use InCognito / InPrivate to avoid these errors, however I would like to know if there is anyway to access multiple domains with different accounts seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox Multi-Account Containers is my solution: https://blog.mozilla.org/firefox/introducing-firefox-multi-account-containers/.

The problem you have is due to the main feature of Azure AD.
It is a Single Sign-On service.
Sign in once, no need to sign in again.
You need isolation which Incognito mode offers.
Firefox Multi-Account Containers takes it a step further and allows you to define multiple accounts, open tabs in the container you want, and single sign-on will be scoped to the container.

Comment: Thanks @juunas!.. But, I'm looking for a workaround for IE, if not atleast for chrome. Can you help?

Comment: There is none. Normal window + InPrivate allows two accounts.

Comment: Thanks Juunas!. :-)